# Extract JSON into Javascript variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I'm new at javascript and here is a newbie question:

In php, there is an [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) method which can import variables from an associative array. For example:

```
$var_array = array("color" => "blue",
                   "size"  => "medium",
                   "shape" => "sphere");
extract($var_array);
// $color is a defined varible here with the value of "blue"
```

I wonder if there is a method in standard Javascript, or in popular libraries like jQuery or underscore, that does the same for a Javascript Object. I mean something like this:

```
jsObject = {"color" : "blue",
            "size"  : "medium",
            "shape" : "sphere"};

extract(jsObject); // Is there such a thing?

// Here, color is a defined variable
```

Comment: No there is no such function, but why do you need that?

Comment: why do you need it? You can just take the JSON and simply translate it as an object using JSON.parse(). Than you can easily access the color value using myObject.color

Comment: you can declare to `window` object (global scope):  `jsObject.forEach(function(value, key){ window[key] = value; });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(k => window[k] = obj[k]);
```

Or to limit the scope of the new variables:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(k => this[k] = obj[k]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
function extract(jsObject){
    for (var key in jsObject) {
       window[key] = jsObject[key];
    }
}




 console.log(size)   //medium
```

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in standard Javascript that works quite like that but if you use ES6 you can destructure your objects like this

```
const obj = {
    color: 'blue',
    size: 'medium',
    shape: 'sphere',
}

const { color, size, shape } = obj;

console.log(color, size, shape) // blue medium sphere
```

You can use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile your code to ES6. It may be a little advanced for you now if you're just starting out so I recommend you stick with the intuitive approach but after a few weeks definitely check out Babel. It gives you some really cool stuff.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with using **window** object:

1. It, and all of its properties are default global variables. Which may not be in interest.
2. There must be an assumption that it exists in all browsers (which it is now). Think about Nodejs

You can do:

```
for (var key in jsObject) {
    eval('var ' + key + ' = ' + jsObject[key]);
}
```

Try this, might help:

```
(function () {
    var jsObject = {color: 'blue'};

    // Dynamically assign to local variables
    for (var key in jsObject) {
        eval('var ' + key + ' = ' + jsObject[key]);
    }

    // Test locally
    console.log(color);
})();

// Test globally
console.log(color);
```

Results:

```
'blue'
[error] color is not defined
```